# Preventing Injection Attacks with Excel Export

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection, export-to-excel, ole

I have posted my code below for an Excel exporting class (most of it anyway). The issue I am incurring is that this export is not safe when it comes to injection attacks. I was easily able to mask the initial command with parameters, however, when I passed the parameterized command to the Export(string) method, it loses the values previously set within the parameters; it only passes the literal string (i.e. SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @Parameter1).
 What I am trying to figure out is a way to prevent this code from being unsafe. I really need this functionality. It has been fine in the past because of the desired audience of the applications, but I cannot use this specific code considering it will be customer facing and more less open to public use. :/ 
 Any suggestions of how I can achieve this goal?

```
public static void Export(string CrossoverStatement = "SELECT * FROM TABLE")
{
    // @@Parameters
    //
    // CrossoverStatement string :
    //     This is the string representation of the procedure executed to obtain the desired crossover query results.

    //Create our database connection as well as the excel reference and workbook/worksheet we are using to export the data
    string ODBCConnection = "SERVER INFO";

    Application xls = new Application();
    xls.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;
    // Create our new excel application and add our workbooks/worksheets
    Workbook Workbook = xls.Workbooks.Add();
    Worksheet CrossoverPartsWorksheet = xls.Worksheets[1];
    // Hide our excel object if it's visible.
    xls.Visible = false;
    // Turn off screen updating so our export will process more quickly.
    xls.ScreenUpdating = false;

    CrossoverPartsWorksheet.Name = "Crossover";
    if (CrossoverStatement != string.Empty)
    {
        CrossoverPartsWorksheet.Select();
        var xlsheet = CrossoverPartsWorksheet.ListObjects.AddEx(SourceType: XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcExternal,
                                                                Source: ODBCConnection,
                                                                Destination: xls.Range["$A$1"]).QueryTable;
        xlsheet.CommandText = CrossoverStatement;
        xlsheet.RowNumbers = false;
        xlsheet.FillAdjacentFormulas = false;
        xlsheet.PreserveColumnInfo = true;
        xlsheet.PreserveFormatting = true;
        xlsheet.RefreshOnFileOpen = false;
        xlsheet.BackgroundQuery = false;
        xlsheet.SavePassword = false;
        xlsheet.AdjustColumnWidth = true;
        xlsheet.RefreshPeriod = 0;
        xlsheet.RefreshStyle = XlCellInsertionMode.xlInsertEntireRows;
        xlsheet.Refresh(false);
        xlsheet.ListObject.ShowAutoFilter = false;
        xlsheet.ListObject.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium16";
        // Unlink our table from the server and convert to a range.
        xlsheet.ListObject.Unlink();
        // Freeze our column headers.
        xls.Application.Rows["2:2"].Select();
        xls.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
        xls.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;
        // Autofit our rows and columns.
        xls.Application.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
        xls.Application.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit();
        // Select the first cell in the worksheet.
        xls.Application.Range["$A$2"].Select();
        // Turn off alerts to prevent asking for 'overwrite existing' and 'save changes' messages.
        xls.DisplayAlerts = false;
    }

    // Make our excel application visible
    xls.Visible = true;

    // Release our resources.
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Workbook);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(CrossoverPartsWorksheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xls);
}
```

Comment: Can you use a non-SQL syntax to get the information that you need from the document?  Can you store the information in a real database instead of an excel file (even if that's a local database on the client machine)?  Are the "valid" queries simple enough that whitelisting the valid characters for the user inputted data can be sufficiently limited, i.e. only alphanumeric values?

Comment: I don't believe a non-SQL syntax is possible as all information is coming directly from our SQL server database. The excel file is required as it will be available at user request, so a database storing the information does us no good at this point. Unfortunately no, there is no possibility of limiting the input or the characters being inputted as the valid input is gathered via thousands of vendors with their own proprietary naming conventions. I have seen almost every character possible through these parts. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best way to complete this request that I could come up with. Perform a parameterized query and pass the resulting data to a table which you can use when calling Export(datatable).

Problem resolved.

```
public static void Export(System.Data.DataTable CrossoverDataTable)
{
    // @@Parameters
    //
    // CrossoverDataTable DataTable :
    //     This is a data table containing information to be exported to our excel application.
    //     Requested as a way to circumvent sql injection opposed to the initial overload accepting only a string .commandtext.

    Application xls = new Application();
    xls.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;

    // Create our new excel application and add our workbooks/worksheets
    Workbook Workbook = xls.Workbooks.Add();
    Worksheet CrossoverPartsWorksheet = xls.Worksheets[1];

    // Hide our excel object if it's visible.
    xls.Visible = false;

    // Turn off screen updating so our export will process more quickly.
    xls.ScreenUpdating = false;

    // Turn off calculations if set to automatic; this can help prevent memory leaks.
    xls.Calculation = xls.Calculation == XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic ? XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual : XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;

    // Create an excel table and fill it will our query table.
    CrossoverPartsWorksheet.Name = "Crossover Data";
    CrossoverPartsWorksheet.Select();
    {

        // Create a row with our column headers.
        for (int column = 0; column < CrossoverDataTable.Columns.Count; column++)
        {
            CrossoverPartsWorksheet.Cells[1, column + 1] = CrossoverDataTable.Columns[column].ColumnName;
        }

        // Export our datatable information to excel.
        for (int row = 0; row < CrossoverDataTable.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < CrossoverDataTable.Columns.Count; column++)
            {
                CrossoverPartsWorksheet.Cells[row + 2, column + 1] = (CrossoverDataTable.Rows[row][column].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    // Freeze our column headers.
    xls.Application.Rows["2:2"].Select();
    xls.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
    xls.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;

    // Autofit our rows and columns.
    xls.Application.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
    xls.Application.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit();

    // Select the first cell in the worksheet.
    xls.Application.Range["$A$2"].Select();

    // Turn off alerts to prevent asking for 'overwrite existing' and 'save changes' messages.
    xls.DisplayAlerts = false;

    // ******************************************************************************************************************
    // This section is commented out for now but can be enabled later to have excel sheets show on screen after creation.
    // ******************************************************************************************************************
    // Make our excel application visible
    xls.Visible = true;

    // Turn screen updating back on
    xls.ScreenUpdating = true;

    // Turn automatic calulation back on
    xls.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic;

    // Release our resources.
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Workbook);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(CrossoverPartsWorksheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xls);
}
```